# Let apache handle 404 error when deemed appropriate by PHP?

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-404

I perfectly know how to create a custom 404 page in PHP, however I'm wondering if there's a way to give back control to to apache and let it produce the proper 404 page, sending right headers, etc. when my logic says so?

I'm looking at [some apache specific functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apache.php) but can't seem to find anything appropriate. Is that really just not possible? I recall something similar available to e.g. mod_perl by having full access to apache internals, where's that equivalent in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My research so far led me to the conclusion that it's not possible to delegate back to Apache from within mod_php like some other technologies, e.g. mod_perl, allow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do what you want to do exactly, but one of your requirements can be met by php, and well, apart from ... I don't really see any other ones.

You can send the correct type of header using the header() function. In my code I usually use the one below.

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
echo "sorry, page not found...";
```

See [function.header.php](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in the php manual for more details.

Comment: I see, sorry. Perhaps clarifying more why you want apache to do it, and not using examples of things you can already do from php might help? PHP can produce a proper 404 page, so there is confusion in your request in that way. Wish I could help more, but I know of no way to return the logic back to apache without doing something dumb like header requesting to a url not handled by php.

Comment: I wanted to take advantage of Apaches mechanism which generates additional headers for 404 pages which I would have to manually add, which I'm not fond of. Seems PHP simply doesn't support this kind of thing.