# Emulate a 403 error page

Tags: php, header, http-status-code-403

I know you can send a header that tells the browser this page is forbidden like:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
```

But how can I also display the custom error page that has been created on the server for this type of error?

By default, just sending the header displays a white page, but I remember a while back reading that you can use the customer error page. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Include the custom error page after changing the header.

Comment: I tried that as well, but things like this are not rendered: <!--#echo var="REDIRECT_STATUS" -->

Comment: So after a lot more search and not finding anything else, I chose to include the page and just swap out the SSI commands with PHP.

Comment: Ryan, that sounds right — to get server-side includes to work, you’d have to call out to Apache again somehow to say, “nevermind, don’t serve this request as PHP, serve 'this page' instead” — or (in a simulation of that behavior), proxying your own site by requesting that 403 page and sending the output back as the original request's response.

Answer (score 81):

Just echo your content after sending the header.

```
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');

echo 'You are forbidden!';
```

[image: forbidden]

Comment: I know I can do that, but how do I use the custom error template that's already setup?

Comment: @Ryan Depends entirely on how your application is setup. It may be possible to just include it. Don't send `Location` header, as it will change the response code.

Comment: This assumes HTTP/1.1 protocol. We now have HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2. Don't use this.

Answer (score 77):

[http_response_code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) was introduced in PHP 5.4 and made the things a lot easier!

```
http_response_code(403);
die('Forbidden');
```

Answer (score 21):

For this you must first say for the browser that the user receive an error 403. For this you can use this code:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" );
```

Then, the script send "error, error, error, error, error.......", so you must stop it. You can use

```
exit;
```

With this two lines the server send an error and stop the script.

Don't forget : that emulate the error, but you must set it in a .htaccess file, with

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error403.php
```

Answer (score 11):

Seen a lot of the answers, but the correct one is to provide the full options for the header function call as per the php manual

```
void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

If you invoke with

```
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden', true, 403);
```

the normal behavior of HTTP 403 as configured with Apache or any other server would follow.

Answer (score 7):

I have read all the answers here and none of them was complete answer for my situation (which is exactly the same in this question) so here is how I gathered some parts of the suggested answers and come up with the exact solution:

1. Land on your server's real 403 page. (Go to a forbidden URL on your server, or go to any 403 page you like)
2. Right-click and select 'view source'. Select all the source and save it to file on your domain like: http://domain.com/403.html
3. now go to your real forbidden page (or a forbidden situation in some part of your php) example: http://domain.com/members/this_is_forbidden.php
4. echo this code below **before** any HTML output or header! (even a whitespace will cause PHP to send HTML/TEXT HTTP Header and it won't work)
   The code below should be your **first line**!

   ```
       <?php header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
       $contents = file_get_contents('/home/your_account/public_html/domain.com/403.html', TRUE);
       exit($contents);
   ```

Now you have the exact solution. I checked and verified with CPANEL Latest Visitors and it is registered as exact 403 event.

Comment: I can be wrong, but I'd say it just prints the php of /home/your_account/public_html/domain.com/403.php.
It don't executes it.

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierVares Yes, it does not execute but it is already a static file, why would you want to execute it. If you still want to execute the included file, use include ("/home/your_account/public_html/domain.com/403.php"); instead.

Comment: Why would it _necessarily_ be a static file ? Yourself wrote (before editing your comment) '.php' as extension, and the OP asks for SSI in his comments.
If it's an .html file, of course you can just echo it.
If it's a .php file, it's assumed to be dynamic - and so you can't just echo it unless you explicitly want the source code.

Comment: I couldn't work with .htaccess ErrorDocument and seems like this is the only solution that works with php header function. I recommend to put the header in a function like e.g. function error403() { //all the codes from @tarik } and just call error403() on pages you need.

Answer (score 4):

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 403     /403.html
```

Comment: typo, it happens, (i had 404 and 403.html)

Comment: Will apache directly show the error page even if it was the user who changed the header? I don't know why that won't work but I'm just wondering...

Comment: @alex, sorry but that happens some times

Comment: The guys here appears to think it's not possible to let apache handle the request if you changed the header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501094/let-apache-handle-404-error-when-deemed-appropriate-by-php

Comment: @Ibrahim AshShohail user changes the header how? The header is generated by the server.

Comment: @Dagon I meant the developer, but technically you are right. It's the server that changed the header. =0

Answer (score 3):

To minimize the duty of the server make it simple:

**.htaccess**

```
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"
```

**PHP**

```
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');

die(); // or your message: die('Forbidden');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ModRewrite:

`RewriteRule ^403.html$ - [F]`

Just make sure you create a blank document called "403.html" in your www root or you'll get a 404 error instead of 403.

Comment: Hmm, well it kinda works. I tried it, but the REQUEST_URI variable will be set to /403.html instead of the resource you're trying to restrict. This could be confusing to users.

Comment: Well you'll have to play with it. ModRewrite is incredibly powerful and it's definitely the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have a scenario with ErrorDocument already defined within your apache conf or .htaccess and want to make those pages appear when manually sending a 4xx status code via php.

Unfortunately this is not possible with common methods because php sends header directly to user's browser (not to Apache web server) whereas ErrorDocument is a display handler for http status generated from Apache.

Answer (score -1):

Refresh the page after sending the 403:

```
<?php 
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
?>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://my.error.page">
</head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: I don't see this as being a very good solution. Why not just send a location header if that's what you're trying to achieve.