# How to set Custom Page for 403 Forbidden Error in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am developing a web site using CodeIgniter. I have already have a custom 404 Error Page. But now i want to add **a custom page for 403 Forbidden Error**. Can you help me?
I have used this code for 404 `$route['404_override'] = 'Error';`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5061734/3419997

Answer (score 0):

I havent used codeigniter for a while... So check `\application\errors\error_404.php` and modify accordingly. let me know if it doesnt work. I check my previous works and see how i managed to customize it.

Comment: i couldn't understand what you mean. So please explain briefly, because i am not genius in php and codeigniter.

Comment: Create a new controller/method for 403 error page and when ever needed set a redirect to this controller. in this controller make sure u set headers $this->output->set_status_header('403'); and then load a custom view of ur choice.

Comment: I mean to find a methord to avoid putting manually where to show '403 Forbidden Error'.  In the case of 404 File Not Found Error there is an option to rout to the 404_page controller by `$route['404_override'] = 'Error';` this code. I want to know is there any method similar to this.

Comment: sorry i dont think there is any function out of the box to override. only way to do is create a custom route and then use route to display 403 page where ever needed, also dont forget to set 403 header.