# If php variable is not like, open other webpage in same window

Tags: php

How can i open another webpage if a varaiable is not like expected, and in the same window?

I have tried variants of:

```
if ($variable <> 2 ) { 'window.location.replace("https://www.somwhere.no/somepage.php","_self")'; }
```

I usually get just a stop in the current webpage.
I am trying to send the command to the user, to load an other page instead.

Comment: You are mixing php with javascript. You can't. You actually are just typing a string, without instructions. If you want to do a redirection in php you can use [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061675/emulate-a-403-error-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: (or athleast it works for me...)

```
if ($variable !=2) { echo ' <script> 
{ 
window.open("https://www.somwhere.no/somepage.php", "_self"); 
} 
</script> ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what you want to achieve, the "not equals" comparison is performed using `!=` or `!==` operators instead of `<>`. Also, redirection in php is performed differently by using, as someone mentioned, a "Location" header.

```
if ($variable !=2) {
    header('Location: https://www.somwhere.no/somepage.php');
    exit;
 }
```

Comment: This only gives a blank page, as in script just stops.